# I imported a pokemon project to gmx

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

// but the code is throwing unexpected terminal operator new

```
function MovePokemon(argument0, argument1) {
    old = argument0;
    new = argument1;

    TPartyID = global.PartyID[old]
    global.PartyID[old] = global.PartyID[new]
    global.PartyID[new] = TPartyID;
```

Comment: My mistake, the project was already in gmx, I imported it to game maker 2 (.yyp)

Comment: have you checked if `new` is a defined argument?

Answer (score 0):

`new` is a keyword in the current versions of GameMaker, so you'll need to rename that variable (say, to `_new`).

The project in question may leave some to be desired given the complete absence of local variable declarations (`var`).

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code in your script to avoid use "new"

```
function MovePokemon(argument0, argument1) {

    TPartyID = global.PartyID[argument0]
    global.PartyID[argument0] = global.PartyID[argument1]
    global.PartyID[argument1] = TPartyID;
```